# how to limit the number posts per page

Tags: wordpress, codex

In creating my theme, I want to show one sticky post in a loop but unfortunately, all sticky posts (there are 5) are displaying. I just want to show 1 or two but I am unable to do so through my coding.
I don't know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong.

```html
<?php
       $query = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_per_page'    => 1,
       'post__in'          => get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'paged'             => $paged,
                        
                    ));
?>
```

Comment: I also tried to remove sticky posts from the loop, using 
'post__not_in'          => get_option('sticky_posts'),
then general flow of loop worked and display 1 post as per query....
but when again in included only sticky post . It didn't work.

Comment: You have a typo there: it's `posts_per_page`, not `post_per_page`.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Now I deleted all sticky post and make a new sticky post.
Now it has become more strange..... My latest sticky post is not visible... Nothing is visible whole container is empty.
Totally messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last sticky post:

```php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
query_posts( $args );
if ( $sticky[0] ) {
    // insert here your stuff...
}
```

Comment: It worked..
but I couldn't understand where I was wrong.